# Finding that no vector in prehilbert space has a certain property

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, continuity, hilbert-spaces

Let $E=C^0([0,1],\mathbb C)$ with the norm derived from the inner product:
$$
   <f,g>=\int_0^1 f(t)\overline {g(t)}dt
$$
I had to show that for the continuous linear transformation, $u:E\to\mathbb C$ given by $u(f)=\int_0^af(t)t^2dt$, where $a\in (0,1)$ fixed, there is no $g\in E$ such that $<f,g>=u(f)$ for all $f\in E$. I have tried many things but I can't find a good argument. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is $l$ in your integral?

Comment: $l$ is a constant between $0$ and $1$, I forgot to mention that sorry.

Comment: Tell us some of the things you've tried.

Comment: Well since we're working on the complex field, I thought maybe assuming there is such a $g$ we could then construct an appropriate $f$ that would lead us to contradiction, for example by concluding that $g$ would not be continuous. I think the idea is to somehow see that $g$ must equal $t^2$ on the interval $[0,a]$, and then $0$  on $(a,0]$. The first part of the problem was to show that $u$ was indeed continuous and to find its norm, which I did. It's $\sqrt{\frac{x^5}{5}}$. So another idea I had was to look for a way to prove that a continuous $g$ like that would pass the bound of the norm..

Comment: I like your idea of seeing that $g(t) = t^2 \chi_{[0,a]}(t)$ is the function that would do the job, but it's not in our space. So that raises the question: Can we recover the value of $g$ at an arbitrary point $t_0$ from the linear functional? Have you looked at a sequence that approximates the delta function?

Comment: BTW, I'd suggest editing your original question to use $a$ instead of $l$, like you did in your comment. It's pretty hard to see the difference between $l$ and $1$ in the upper limit of the integral.

Comment: I did approximate the delta function with a sequence to find the norm. But I can't find how to use that in this part...
And thanks for the tip, I did change it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115457/discussion-between-jonathanz-supports-monicac-and-xu-pi).

Comment: FYI - `\langle f, g \rangle` gives $\langle f, g \rangle$, which is nicer than $<f,g>$